# Matrix translations and scales

Tags: android, matrix, android-view

I'm trying to zoom a bunch of views relative to another one. So let's say I have an `ImageView` that has a map as its `ImageDrawable`.
That map has some POI drawn on it (in the bitmap) and I want to draw my views above those POIs because I want them to be touchable.

I've some ideas on how to achieve this:

1 - I just simple drag/zoom that image and regarding it's position and scale I can get the POI position using also the `MotionEvent` getX and getY.
This is the ugliest yet the fastest solution.

2 - Use `GoogleMaps` with my image has a map image overlay (I could use `Mapbox`, or `Android` `Ground Overlays` to achieve this). I would shift the map to a "nowhere" location, draw my custom markers and jobs done. `GoogleMaps` would handle my zoom, drag, POI touch, etc...

3 - The solution I'm using and the one I like the most: Having a **ViewContainer** with all its child views who will suffer some matrix transformations.

Let's see some code:

```
public class ZoomableContainer extends FrameLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final float THRESHOLD = 50;
    private List<ImageView> mChildViews;
    private final GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mSavedMatrix = new Matrix();

    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mMode = NONE;

    private PointF mStart = new PointF();
    private PointF mMid = new PointF();
    private float mOldDist = 1f;
    private float[] mLastEvent = null;

    public ZoomableContainer(ZoomInActivity context, List<ImageView> child) {
        super(context);
        mChildViews = new ArrayList<>(child);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new SingleTapConfirm());
        setClipChildren(false);
        setClipToPadding(false);

        for (ImageView view : mChildViews) {
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            addView(view);
        }
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            getViewInBounds(event);
        } else {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mSavedMatrix.set(mMatrix);
                    mStart.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mMode = DRAG;
                    mLastEvent = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    mOldDist = spacingBetweenTouch(event);
                    if (mOldDist > 10f) {
                        mSavedMatrix.set(mMatrix);
                        midPointBetweenTouch(mMid, event);
                        mMode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    mLastEvent = new float[4];
                    mLastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                    mLastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                    mLastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mMode = NONE;
                    mLastEvent = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mMode == DRAG) {
                        mMatrix.set(mSavedMatrix);
                        float dx = event.getX() - mStart.x;
                        float dy = event.getY() - mStart.y;
                        mMatrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    } else if (mMode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacingBetweenTouch(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            mMatrix.set(mSavedMatrix);
                            float scale = (newDist / mOldDist);
                            mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, mMid.x, mMid.y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                for (ImageView view : mChildViews) {
                    view.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float spacingBetweenTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPointBetweenTouch(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private void getViewInBounds(MotionEvent event) {
        // handle POI onClick() logic...
    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So with this `View` I can **DRAG** and **ZOOM** it's chill. The `List<ImageView> child` contains all my POI and the MAP (the child[0]). Now it’s where it gets tricky:

- If a child view is at (0,0) the scale works great, that view gets correctly scaled and translated relative to the MAP view.
- If a child is at `setX(100)` and `setY(100)` for example, the scale will work but its position will not change relative to de MAP view.

I have some questions:
1 - Why after applying a matrix transformation `getX()`, `getY()`, `getScale()`… won’t get updated?
2 - How can I achieve what I want, a `postScale` where all views will suffer a scale (working) and a correct translation (not working) relative to the MAP view (like when they are at the same origin points at scale = 1)

I’ve tried (inside de last `if` after `view.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);` in `onTouch`) to use the view new matrix and consult the `Matrix.MTRANS_X` or `Matrix.MSCALE_X` in order to translate the view back (after the scale) to the desired position relative to the map but with no luck.

I guess I’m not that far from the solution, or maybe I am, but can you point me towards to it?
Thanks for your help, hope I have been clear.

Comment: instead of having several `ImageViews` just draw it by yourself (you will have a full control over that): see [this](http://pastebin.com/pD24qHY7)

Comment: @pskink So instead of having a parent responsible for changing all its child you're suggestion is having all the child responsible for their changes, and the parent will call onTouch for all of them? Sounds nice, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: there are no children: see my code i posted or better yet [this](http://pastebin.com/5wxp3cEe), just call `setContentView(new ScaleView(this));` in `Activity#onCreate` to see how it works - you will see 3 fake POIs (colored circles), just try to tap on them after scaling and scrolling the view

Comment: @pskink thank you so much for your input and sample. I'm not at home at the moment so I can't run it, but I've read the code and it looks such an elegant approach. When I get back home I'll try it and I'll get back at you ;)
Thanks once again.

Comment: Claro, não há problema

Comment: It works! It's exactly what I want :) I was somehow close to your approach in one of my first approaches but then I've lost it. My ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector were equal. I've only 2 doubts and they are: 1 - why do we need to canvas.concat(matrix) instead of canvas.setMatrix(matrix)? 2 - When finding if a POI is clicked why do we use the inverted instead of the matrix to grab the mapPoints? Muito obrigado!

Comment: ad 1) use `canvas.setMatrix(matrix)` and you will see the difference... ;-) ad 2) you could use "normal" matrix (not inverted) but you would need to call mapPoints twice, with inverted matrix the calculations are less complex

Comment: BTW if you want to speed the drawing up (when you have hundreds POIs for example) you can use `Canvas#quickReject` which works quite nice even with the transformed `Canvas`

Comment: Thanks once again for your tip, I'll never have hundreds of POIs, (probably 100 tops) but I definitely will look into it!